# How to write single quote (') and double quote (") to a file from terminal?

Tags: shell, file, terminal, command-line-interface, echo

While writing to a file from terminal using 'echo', I could write everything except both quotes together. When trying to write/append lines of python code, to a file, that contains both single and double quotation marks like

```
echo "url = "http://mydummyurl.xyz" 
names = ['name1', 'name2']" > somefile.txt
```

or

```
echo 'url = "http://mydummyurl.xyz" 
names = ['name1', 'name2']' > somefile.txt
```

What is written in somefile.txt is either

```
url = http://mydummyurl.xyz
names = ['name1', 'name2']
```

or

```
url = "http://mydummyurl.xyz"
names = [name1, name2]
```

depending on what I am using to enclose the string after echo. Observe that in strings written in files are missing either single quote or double code used as python syntax. How can I write to file keeping all the necessary syntax intact including both single and double quotations?

Comment: what do you mean `echo is writing`? what did you do exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading description. Edited that to clear confusion. I actually meant the content that was written in file using echo 'text' > somefile.txt command.

Comment: What you want is called "escaping" and uses the ```\``` in front of characters that should do "something special" like not closing the string (using `\"`) or forcing a newline (`\n`), or actually writing the escape characters itself (using `\\`). It's covered in any tutorial on how to write strings to anywhere, and should be pretty easy to look up once you know it's called "escaping".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need escape the quotes:

```
kent$  echo  "single:''';double:\"\"\"" > foo

kent$  cat foo
single:''';double:"""
```